# django date field with year and month inputs

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have a django form that takes the year and month as integers, and uses these inputs to add the concatenated value (year-month) to a charfield called date:

```
'date': str(form.cleaned_data['year']) + '-' + str(form.cleaned_data['month'])
```

django model:

```
year = models.IntegerField()
month = models.IntegerField()
date = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

[image: Input]

the issue, as shown in the chart below, 2021-12 is being treated as smaller than 2021-4.
How can I create a django date field that only takes month and year as inputs and can have the result being showed in the right ascending order, 2021-4 then 2021-12 OR in the form of 2021, April then 2021, December.

[image: Output]

Comment: I believe that it's happening since it's compared lexicographically. that means that it see "-12" as before "-4" (same as it would be in a real dictionary).

Comment: can you share more of your code? where and when is this comparison happening?

Comment: At least you should add one leading `0` if the month has only one character - it might solve a kind of alphabetical order. Anyway, I don't know how the chart is built, but using real dates, then format display, looks to me a better solution (even if your date is the 1st of each month)

Comment: @Christophe Adding a 0 solved the issue, thank you!